# Assign domain to a subdomain in a Heroku application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I am not sure if the following scenario can be done on Heroku:

- I have an application that runs on Heroku (`myapp.herokuapp.com`) in which each user can get a subdomain like `foo.example.com`. From what I read, this can be done by wildcarding the subdomain. Adding `*.example.com` to the Heroku domains and then set the DNS provider to point to the Heroku application (`myapp.herokuapp.com`)
- Then, they should be able to link `bar.com` to `foo.example.com`. But, how can this be achieved?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I to get it working like this:

**Add the following CNAMES**

- *.example.com -> myapp.herokuapp.com
- bar.com -> foo.example.com (look for host instead of subdomain inside application and load the needed data based on that)

**Add the domaines on Heroku**

- *.example.com
- bar.com

Answer (score -1):

The Heroku Dev Center has an article that is kept up to date and answers all of this:

- [Heroku Dev Center: Custom Domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

You CNAME `*.example.com` to your Heroku app, and you add `*.example.com` to your Heroku domains. It's up to your application code to make sense of it all after that.